# REQUIRED: The theme uses the register_post_type() function, which is plugin-territory

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, customization, themes

I am developing a car rental theme, but I encountered a big problem, when I upload the theme I get the "REQUIRED: The theme uses the register_post_type() function, which is plugin-territory" the problem is that they won't allow me to keep my custom post types in my functions.php file, and making a custom plugin and requiring with TGMPA is also forbidden,only plugins from the Wordpress repository is allowed so I am really stuck in the middle. I am not sure If I have to upload the custom plugins to Wordpress ORG because it is a theme specific plugin and not a general one. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The simple answer is that, yes, you have to create a separate plugin and add it to wordpress.org. Not sure what the the specific problem is?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, I guess I am uploading the plugins separately!

Comment: theme uses the register_post_type() function is the Warning that I get.